# Printer & Roku facing trouble connecting to ARRIS SURFboard SBG6580-2

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I recently moved to a new place and had to buy a new cable based modem-router as this new place supports only xfinity.

I bought the following modem: [https://www.amazon.com/ARRIS-SURFboard-SBG6580-2-DOCSIS-2-4Ghz/dp/B0100KRBA6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0100KRBA6)

At present, there are 3 mackbooks, 2 iphones, 1 roku, 1 tv, 1 printer and 1 other device connected with this network. Howevever, I am facing difficulty finding the printer and roku:

**Printer:**
I have to restart my printer everytime I want to print, otherwise I get a message that the printer is offline or not responding. I have the following printer: [https://www.amazon.com/Brother-Monochrome-Multifunction-DCPL2550DW-Replenishment/dp/B00MFG57ZK/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1535234267&sr=8-3&keywords=laser%2Bprinter%2Bscanner&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MFG57ZK)

**Roku:**
The same thing happens with my Roku. I have to restart it everytime to be able to cast on youtube on Roku from my phone/laptop.

Everything worked fine before the move. I have a suspicion that this problem is because of some faulty network config.

Any suggestions / recommendations on what might be causing the issue or how can I debug it?

Comment: @alex the device IS a router. To the OP, what status do these devices show for their WiFi connection? Have you run a network test from the Roku or Printer during these problematic times? Are you using the 5Ghz band? If you moved and are trying to use 2.4Ghz it very well may be completed saturated in your new area and not working well.